# Spreading out data from bursts

Tags: algorithm, trafficshaping

I am trying to spread out data that is received in bursts. This means I have data that is received by some other application in large bursts. For each data entry I need to do some additional requests on some server, at which I should limit the traffic. Hence I try to spread up the requests in the time that I have until the next data burst arrives.

Currently I am using a [token-bucket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket) to spread out the data. However because the data I receive is already badly shaped I am still either filling up the queue of pending request, or I get spikes whenever a bursts comes in. So this algorithm does not seem to do the kind of shaping I need.

What other algorithms are there available to limit the requests? I know I have times of high load and times of low load, so both should be handled well by the application.

I am not sure if I was really able to explain the problem I am currently having. If you need any clarifications, just let me know.

**EDIT**:

I'll try to clarify the problem some more and explain, why a simple rate limiter does not work.

The problem lies in the bursty nature of the traffic and the fact, that burst have a different size at different times. What is mostly constant is the delay between each burst. Thus we get a bunch of data records for processing and we need to spread them out as evenly as possible before the next bunch comes in. However we are not 100% sure when the next bunch will come in, just aproximately, so a simple `divide time by number of records` does not work as it should.

A rate limiting does not work, because the spread of the data is not sufficient this way. If we are close to saturation of the rate, everything is fine, and we spread out evenly (although this should not happen to frequently). If we are below the threshold, the spreading gets much worse though.

I'll make an example to make this problem more clear:

Let's say we limit our traffic to 10 requests per seconds and new data comes in about every 10 seconds.

When we get 100 records at the beginning of a time frame, we will query 10 records each second and we have a perfect even spread. However if we get only 15 records we'll have one second where we query 10 records, one second where we query 5 records and 8 seconds where we query 0 records, so we have very unequal levels of traffic over time. Instead it would be better if we just queried 1.5 records each second. However setting this rate would also make problems, since new data might arrive earlier, so we do not have the full 10 seconds and 1.5 queries would not be enough. If we use a token bucket, the problem actually gets even worse, because token-buckets allow bursts to get through at the beginning of the time-frame.

However this example over simplifies, because actually we cannot fully tell the number of pending requests at any given moment, but just an upper limit. So we would have to throttle each time based on this number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem within the domain of [control theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_theory).  Specifically, I'm thinking a [PID controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) might work.

A first crack at the problem might be dividing the number of records by the estimated time until next batch.  This would be like a P controller - proportional only.  But then you run the risk of overestimating the time, and building up some unsent records.  So try adding in an I term - integral - to account for built up error.

I'm not sure you even need a derivative term, if the variation in batch size is random.  So try using a PI loop - you might build up some backlog between bursts, but it will be handled by the I term.

If it's unacceptable to have a backlog, then the solution might be more complicated...

Comment: This is very close to the idea I am currently using. Just divide the number of requests by the estimated amount of time per burst. My calculations show that if the burst come regulary, we handle 2/3 of the data, which is acceptable. I will also have a look on the way the I term works, so maybe we can even get the last 1/3 out as well.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no other constraints, what you should do is figure out the maximum data rate that you are comfortable with sending additional requests, and limit your processing speed according to that.  Then monitor what is happening.  If that gets through all of your requests quickly, then there is no harm . If its sustained level of processing is not fast enough, then you need more capacity.

Comment: That's basicly what we are currently doing with the token bucket (the token bucket just adds more fancy). However this is not what we really need, because we have different times with different amount of traffic and we still need to spread out no matter what kind we are currently seeing. If we just rate limit independently of the current traffic, we will go faster than necessary during low load times, where we could spread out more evenly.

Comment: +LiKao: Why is it good to spread out traffic more evenly at low times?  In any case you can just set a rate cap which is a fixed percentage of the current backlog per minute.  When a burst comes in the rate raises, then exponentially dies down.  And you'd have a target time to get the average job done of, say, 30 min.

Comment: We need to keep the traffic on the server as low as possible at all times. So if we have bursty traffic, we might still get moments, where we produce too much load. For now I think I have a solution, which is basically the same as the dynamic rate change that you propose. For this I just try to estimate how much we need to get done in which estimated time and then divide the two. My calculations show that this way we get an exponential decay and we can get out 2/3 of the traffic, the rest then gets pushed out with the next burst, so we are fine.